# ID number zero, one, o and i in query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

We have a system that creates a 5 digit alpha-numeric string of numbers and letters. Originally, I had the full alphabet and 0-9 so something like the following was possible:

```
0O1I0
```

Because different fonts may be used on different systems, there was confusion between the o's and i's so I updated the function to only include the numbers. Because there are historical items with the "o" and "i" items I have been asked to modify our search to automatically look for a zero if an o is entered and a 1 if an i is entered (or vice versa).

These are 5 digit ids with 2 possible values for the specific character. I'm thinking I could loop over the value with PHP prior to writing the query to build a list of options and then check if "IN (list of items)" in my query. I don't know if there's something built in that I'm missing though in MySQL like..

```
WHERE ID = o/0, i/1, etc.
```

Comment: so something like: `WHERE id = this OR id = that` ?

Comment: @OliverQueen that wouldn't work the number of possible combinations is too great. E.g. for `id = 'io'` he would have to check for `io`, `i0`, `1o` and `10`...

Comment: @Oliver Queen: It is ok if it returns more than one item, so I was going to get a list of possibilities and then do IN ('0O1IO','00110', etc). Realistically there may be one or two instances of the character in the ID but the possibility could exist for all 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how about parsing the `id` in php, replacing every occurence of `0` or `O` with regex string `[o0]`, and similarly replacing `i` and `1` with `[i1]`.
Then you could use this string in your query like this

```
WHERE id REGEXP '...[i1]...[o0]...'
```

The php code could look like this

```
  $id = '0O1I0';
  $id = preg_replace('/[i1]/i', '[i1]', $id);
  $id = preg_replace('/[o0]/i', '[o0]', $id);
  echo $id; // [i1][o0][i1][o0][o0]
  ...
  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ... WHERE id REGEXP '$id'");
```

Comment: Reading here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html. Would I then look for ABC10 to be... WHERE id REGEP 'ABC[i1][o0]' ? If so, that looks like it may be EXACTLY what I need

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
select <stuff> from <table>
where replace(replace(upper(id), 'I', '1'), 'O', '0') like '%<number-search-term>%'
```

EDIT (more detail)

replace() in mysql takes three arguments: the original term, what to look for, and what to swap it with. In the where clause I did a nested replace. The inner one replaced any instances of I with 1 and the outer one took the inner replace as its argument (so with all Is as 1s) and replaced any Os with 0s. This is then compared against the number search term (I used a like statement).

Comment: Care to explain this?

Comment: This query is only a theoretical solution. In the real world it doesn't "run"; it crawls. It cannot use any index and it is forced to analyze each and every row of the table.